# Arc connectedness of product spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is  arc connected-ness well-behaved with respect to products?

That is -

> $\prod X_\alpha$ is arc connected iff $X_\alpha$ is arc connected $\forall \alpha$

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3779642) on MathStackexchange, an answer is provided only for the reverse implication, that is  -

> If $X_\alpha$ is arc connected $\forall \alpha$, then $\prod X_\alpha$ is arc connected

However, I wasn't able to get an answer for the forward implication, nor have I been able to find it in any book or from Googling. So, is the forward implication true, or is there a counterexample for the same?

Comment: They are equivalent when $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff because in this context path-connected implies arc-connected.  I will now assume that you are asking about T$_1$ spaces.

Comment: In fact, I'm asking for general $X_\alpha$, which need not even be $T_0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false when the spaces are not Hausdorff. Let $X$ be the line with two origins $\{O_1,O_2\}$ and $Y$ be the usual line. Then $X\times Y$ is arc connected because you can pick an arc that starts at $(O_1,y_1)$ travels outside $\{O_1,O_2\}\times Y$ and then comes back to $(O_2,y_2)$, but $X$ itself is not arc connected.

Comment: Sorry it's early in the morning and I might be missing something obvious, but writing $X=\mathbb{R}\sqcup\mathbb{R}/\sim$ why can't I take the path $[0,\frac{1}{2}]\to[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ on the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]\to[\frac{1}{2},0]$ on the second copy to link the two origins?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud that shows that it is path connected, which is different from arc connected. You would need your map from $[0,1]\to X$ to be injective.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks, I had never come across this notion tbh.

Comment: Also since the projection of a path is still a path, the implication of the OP is true for path connected..